# How to obtain the size relationship between parameters a and b based on known conditions?

Tags: equation-solving

Known conditions are:

```
Log[b, N] < Log[a, N] < 0, N > 1, a + b == 1
```

[image]

above step is solved by hand

```
In[21]:= Clear["Global`*"]
Reduce[{Log[b, N] < Log[a, N] < 0, N > 1, a + b == 1}, a, Reals]

Out[22]= 1/2 < b < 1 && N > 1 && a == 1 - b
```

Unable to find the size relationship between a and b using the above code

Comment: The output seems correct.  What do you find wrong with it?

Comment: I want to get the result``` a<b<1```

Comment: Exactly the same answer:  1/2 < b < 1 && N > 1 && a == 1 - b

Comment: `N` is a reserved symbol.

Comment: I don't think you can force `Reduce` to output `a<b<1`, but you can evaluate it separately after getting the ConditionalExpression from `SolveValues`:



`aVal = First@SolveValues[{Log[b, n] < Log[a, n] < 0, n > 1, a + b == 1}, a, Reals]`
`Simplify[aVal < b < 1]` (*True with conditions on b and n*)